# Trying to toggle Celsius and Fahrenheit for different cities when clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery

The issue I am having is that the temperature button only seems to toggle the Celsius and Fahrenheit of the local weather. I would like to be able to do this with the other cities that can be clicked on above and below the container. I have tried to implement this on the Dubai weather to try and get this working, but I get an odd result whereby the C becomes capitalised, with no change in the temperature value or the text. Can anyone help to get this working? nce this has been sorted, I will apply it to the other cities. I have provided a Codepen below as well as some of my code used to try and get this working.

```
  function toggleTemp(lat, lon) {
    var weatherAPI =
  "https://fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current?lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon;

$.getJSON(weatherAPI, function(data) {
  $(".temp-slider").on("click", function() {
    var tempC = data.main.temp;
    var tempF = tempC * 9 / 5 + 32;

    if (toggleF) {
      $("#weather-degrees").html(Math.round(tempF) + "&deg;F");
      $("#temp-slider-text").html("Fahrenheit");
      toggleF = false;
    } else if (toggleF == false) {
      $("#weather-degrees").html(Math.round(tempC) + "&deg;C");
      $("#temp-slider-text").html("Celsius");
      toggleF = true;
    }
  });
});
```

}

https://codepen.io/KUBIX90/pen/NwWvNb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything in your codepen works (mostly) AFTER first clicking Dubai.

You have `var toggleF = true;` and `toggleTemp(25.2, 55.27);` in that function, but not in the others, so that's the point of difference.

However doing `var toggleF = true` makes toggleF a local variable colliding with the global one. You should have something like `toggleF = !toggleF` instead, but since toggleF is ALSO changed in toggleTemp() you should just remove it.

Additionally your `toggleTemp` function makes a new call to `fcc-weather-api.glitch.me/api/current` every time the degree type is toggled. If the user clicks the button faster than the http request returns this can cause errors. Better to keep the temperature in a variable and only make a new request to the API when the user chooses a different location. That will let your degree type display change be completely client side.

I think the reason the slider doesn't work until after you click Dubai is that you have the block that starts:

```
$.getJSON(weatherAPI, function(data) {
  $(".slider").on("click", function() {
```

is *inside* the `toggleTemp()` function (which is only called in the dubai button click event). It's therefore not attached to clicks on .slider class objects until the toggle function has been run at least once. Worse, every time you click Dubai, you invoke it again so you get weird behavior from double-running the code inside it in one click.

TL;DR do the following:

- define your `.slider").on("click"` function on its own as soon as the page is ready.
- the only thing it should do is invert `toggleF` and update the GUI
- get and save the temperature from the api only when the user switches locations.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help, I'm not sure i fully understand though. I've tried taking out the API call and the $getJSON method before, but they always cause errors, even when I place them elsewhere, so I've kept them in. I do understand though that calling the API every time when clicking the toggle is not ideal, but I don't know how to solve this. I also don't understand the second bullet point either, what exactly needs updating in the global GUI?

Comment: by update the GUI I mean things like `$("#weather-degrees").html(Math.round(tempF) + "&deg;F");` where you're changing the tag text which updates the what the user sees.

I'd have to see the code/errors from moving the $getJSON method to help there, but since it's a structural problem with the code there's going to be more to it than just dragging a block into a different scope.
Here's one way to do it: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BmoYNo

Comment: Thanks for the example, makes it clearer what you were explaining before. Your solution is very helpful and I could definitely learn a thing or two from it given my current level of knowledge. Didn't think I could set the data as a variable globally and then work from there, thanks alot!